# subprocess.communicate only reads on exit

Tags: python, subprocess

I am trying to run a subprocess in a thread that will output data periodically(but more often than once a second)

However when trying to read the stdout of the process, `communicate(timeout=2)` always encounters a TimeoutError, even when valid stdout data should be available.

The code runs in a flask application, in a thread spawned with `daemon=True`.

The process i am trying to run is

```
print("A")
time.sleep(1)
print("B")
time.sleep(5)
print("C")
exit()
```

Which should be giving me both "A" and "B" without hitting the timeout.

This is the loop that should give me output:

```
with Popen(
        args=[get_python_path(), path.join(
            self.path, "output.py")],
        stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, universal_newlines=True) as proc:
    self.status = RNNTrainer.STARTED
    status = None
    while status == None:
        try:
            stdout, stderr = proc.communicate(timeout=2)
            print(stdout)
            status = proc.returncode
        except TimeoutExpired as err:
            print("Timeout Expired")
            proc.poll()
            status == proc.returncode
        except Exception as err:
            print("Unhandled Ex")
```

I would like to see the output like:

```
A
B
Timeout expired <-This after the sleep(5) call
C
```

However, instead i get

```
Timeout expired
Timeout expired
Timeout expired
A
B
C
```

In other words. `.communicate` only works when the program terminates. Otherwise it just ends

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `flush=True` to `print()` calls

```
print("A", flush=True)
time.sleep(1)
print("B", flush=True)
time.sleep(5)
print("C", flush=True)
exit()
```

This force [`print()`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#print) to flush the stream.

> [When interactive, stdout and stderr streams are line-buffered. Otherwise, they are block-buffered like regular text files. You can override this value with the -u command-line option.](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/sys.html#sys.stdout)

Comment: I won't have direct control over the application being run unfortunately

Comment: Add `-u` option of the Python interpreter to the subprocess call. Or set the env var `PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1`. See the updated answer.

Comment: Or for non-Python stuff using standard streams (without adjusting their buffering) `stdbuf -oL real_app_to_run` may do the trick.